# replace for loop in r with function from apply family (large data sets)

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I'm looking at a problem where we are trying to create time series differences for a large numbers of pairs (+40 000) where the time series has (+150 daily points)

Each row is representing a pair of two individuals we want to compare

```
pairs = data.frame("number" = c(1,2,3,4),
                   "name1" = c("A","B","C","D"),
                   "name2" = c("B","D","D","A")
                               )

pairs$name1 <- as.character(pairs$name1)   
pairs$name2 <- as.character(pairs$name2)
```

Each row is representing time series data for a particular individual

```
ts = data.frame("name" = c("A","B","C","D"),
                        "day1" = c(10,12,54,13),
                        "day2" = c(2,8,47,29),
                        "day3" = c(1,5,14,36)
                             )
ts$name <- as.character(ts$name)
```

I have the following R Code where the goal is to create for each pair of individuals (so 4 in my example) a new data frame that has the difference of their daily time series from the ts data frame. This works but is extremely slow when I try to run it on my real data set where pairs has 40 000 rows and ts about 150 columns. Anyone has an idea of how I could speed this up? I tried to use lapply but cant figure how to create the difference and store it in new time series. Thanks!!

```
diffs<-data.frame(matrix(ncol=ncol(ts)))
colnames(diffs)<-colnames(ts)

  for (row in 1:nrow(pairs)){
      row1<-ts[(ts$name==pairs[row,"name1"]),]
      row2<-ts[(ts$name==pairs[row,"name2"]),]
      difference<-rbind(row1,row2)
      difference[3,1]<-pairs[row,"number"]
      difference[3,2:ncol(difference)]<-difference[1,2:ncol(difference)]-difference[2,2:ncol(difference)]
      diffs<-rbind(diffs,difference[3,])
                   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few remarks up front:

i) `data.frame()` has an argument `stringsAsFactors`, which you can set to `FALSE`, i.e.:

```
pairs = data.frame(
    "number" = c(1,2,3,4),
    "name1" = c("A","B","C","D"),
    "name2" = c("B","D","D","A"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

ii) speeding up your code is not really a matter of replacing the *for-loop* with an `apply`, but rather a matter of data structures and processing efficiency. Relying on a package / function that internally loops in C++ rather than R or writing C++ code yourself will give you the biggest boost.

iii) I'll also provide a larger dummy example here, such that you and others can test and compare times a little easier:

```
# all combination of LETTERS, including identity pairs like A~A
pairs = cbind.data.frame(
    "number" = seq(1, 676),
    setNames(expand.grid(LETTERS, LETTERS), nm = c("name1", "name2"))
)
# expand.grid produces factor columns
pairs$name1 <- as.character(pairs$name1)
pairs$name2 <- as.character(pairs$name2)

ts = cbind.data.frame(
    "name" = LETTERS,
    matrix(sample.int(100, 150*26, replace = TRUE), ncol = 150),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
names(ts)[-1] <- paste0("day", names(ts)[-1])
```

iv) an improved version of your loop could then look like:

```
# initialize full matrix (since the ID is a number too), allocating necessary memory
diffs2 <- matrix(0, ncol = ncol(ts), nrow = nrow(pairs))
colnames(diffs2) <- colnames(ts)
# first column is given
diffs2[, 1] <- pairs$number

for (row in 1:nrow(pairs)) {
  row1 <- as.vector(as.matrix(ts[ts$name==pairs[row,"name1"], -1]))
  row2 <- as.vector(as.matrix(ts[ts$name==pairs[row,"name2"], -1]))
  diffs2[row, -1] <- row1 - row2
}
```

this is already several times faster than what you had, but illustrates the **awkwardness** of having a `data.frame` object for a *time-series*, which should instead be an object of a class that allows to work with the numeric data more directly / efficiently (there are several packages that offer time-series classes).

Now for an answer that is still fairly simple yet rather fast, using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
# simple way of measuring time
start <- Sys.time()

xx <- tidyr::gather(ts, key = "day", value = "value", 2:151)
yy <- dplyr::left_join(pairs, xx, by = c("name1" = "name"))
zz <- dplyr::left_join(yy, xx, by = c("name2" = "name", "day" = "day"))
res <- dplyr::mutate(zz, diff = value.x - value.y)

end <- Sys.time()

duration <- end - start
```

duration

> Time difference of 0.06700397 secs

You can also try the approaches from the previous two answers, it's clear that the `mapply` solution will be slow and the `data.table` one isn't working fully yet and already looks slower and more complicated.

Comment: why is not working fully yet ? It is not complicated either to my point, quite clear and simple operations

Comment: have you tried with my dummy data example for pairs and ts above?

Comment: RolandASc your solution using tidyr and dplyr is very elegant and extremely fast when I apply it to my large data set! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have a data.table solution to help.
The idea is to switch to long format to be able to use grouping operation (equivalent to apply) and create permutated column to make the pairs:

```
name1idx <- unlist(lapply(pairs$name1,function(x){grep(x,ts$name)}))
name2idx <- unlist(lapply(pairs$name2,function(x){grep(x,ts$name)}))

plouf <-melt(setDT(ts),measure.vars = patterns("^day"),variable.name = "day")
plouf[,name1 := name[name1idx],by = day]
plouf[,value1 := value[name1idx],by = day]
plouf[,name2 := name[name2idx],by = day]
plouf[,value2 := value[name2idx],by = day]
plouf[,diff := value1 - value2]
plouf[,.(day,diff),by = .(name1,name2)]

    name1 name2  day diff
 1:     A     B day1   -2
 2:     A     B day2   -6
 3:     A     B day3   -4
 4:     B     D day1   -1
 5:     B     D day2  -21
 6:     B     D day3  -31
 7:     C     D day1   41
 8:     C     D day2   18
 9:     C     D day3  -22
10:     D     A day1    3
11:     D     A day2   27
12:     D     A day3   35
```

`name1idx` and `name1idx` are the index of `ts$name` corresponding to `pairs$name1` and `pairs$name2`. You can have this way all the pairs.

Comment: Hi denis, problem is that some of the names in name2 column might not be in the name1 column, for example the pair could have been A and L instead of A and B.

Comment: I edited the solution so it should work in any case. I suppose all the names are in ts$name, that is the data.frame with the data. I am currious to know how much time you will gain. Tell us, and don't forget to accept the answer if it does answer the question

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to in which use of column names is dynamic and no column name to be used other than `name`. `mapply`, `dplyr` and `reshape2` has been used for this solution.

```
# library(reshape2)
# A function which will filter value based on pairs
matchPair <- function(x, y){
  matchedRow <- ts %>% 
    filter(name == x | name == y) %>% 
    select(-name)

  data.frame(diff(as.matrix(matchedRow))) %>% 
    mutate(name = paste0(x, '~',y))
}

df.r <-do.call(rbind,mapply(matchPair, pairs$name1, pairs$name2,
               SIMPLIFY = FALSE))

# Row names are not meaningful. Hence remove those.
row.names(df.r) <- NULL

#Result
#> df.r
#  day1 day2 day3 name
#1    2    6    4  A~B
#2    1   21   31  B~D
#3  -41  -18   22  C~D
#4    3   27   35  D~A
```